# How to set maximum limit of progress bar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want my progress bar's maximum limit according to user
Like its default value is 100 but I dont want that fixed limit.

User Will enter value for "maximum_limit"=?

```
while(progress!=maximum_limit)
 {
 progress++;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: progressbar.setMax()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the user to enter a value using EditText and then use this value when you set the progress bar max:

```
probressbar.setMax(value);
```

Comment: Values which should be inserted, they should be in lower case in order to indiciate that it's just a value not a class

Comment: got it my bad :)